# Python error when using /play command on Discord

Tags: python, syntax, discord, arguments, command

this is the error I've recieved when I tried to use /play (/pusti on my lang) command on Discord in order to play a song from YT:

> 2023-12-01 21:25:11 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command pusti
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
> ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "E:\discord-bot\main.py", line 149, in pusti
> voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
> ^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
> File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

And this is the command I try to use on Discord:

```
@client.command(name = "pusti", aliases = ["p", "play", "playing"], help = "Pušta pesmu sa tvog linka. ")    
    async def pusti(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            await ctx.send("➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nUđi prvo na neki voice kanal! \n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖\nTvoja pesma je sada u redu za čekanje. \n➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖➖")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)
```

I've done everything the same as it is in course video, but somehow mine stuff does not work. Please help someone!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the function `pusti` does not receive the argument `ctx` correctly as the error clearly states:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'` Meaning `ctx` is passed as a string, which is probably (and this is me just assuming) because your function is not inside of a class, meaning that you don't need the parameter `self`. And the `@client.command` decorator passes the context and arguments meaning `self` will be the context and `ctx` will be the arguments. This is likely not what you want.

Because of that changing the function definition to `async def pusti(ctx, *args)` will do the trick, if my assumptions are correct.